# How to store MKAnnotationViews with their corresponding MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I want to drop a bunch of pins for hotels on a map.  I have a MKAnnotation class, 
and a view (MKAnnotationView) and I also have a class Hotel which has all information about the hotel

In terms of design how should these two work together.  Should I have 2 classes or should I just combine both into a single class that inherits from MKAnnotationView and implements MKAnnotation protocol?

Because when I drop a pin I need to have all the details about the pin at hand if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mix model and view so the hotel and the annotation view should be separate classes. But I see no reason why the hotel class should not directly conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. Why did you separate this into another class?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ole. I use NSManagedObjects that conform to the MKAnnotation protocol (coordinate, title, subtitle, even region).  That way I can effectively pass those around and maintain all the relevant information. I haven't figured out the best way to do this with MKPolylines or Polygons, however.